# CentOS 7 Firewalld zone configuration for private web application

Tags: centos, firewall, firewalld

I have read all the `man` pages related to `firewalld` and also explored all of the files that come pre-installed in `firewalld` before it is configured.  **How can I configure the `zones` of the `firewall` to provide maximal security for a `private web application`?**

Here is the use case:

```
1.) Twenty known users will have http/https access to the web  
    application from specific machines.  
2.) One administrator will have remote ssh login access.
3.) The app will send and receive SSL email with the 20 users, the 
    administrator, and with a known group of other users that will 
    change over time and that will be defined by the users through 
    the web application.
4.) The app includes a database, a war file, and uses various services.  
5.) All usage not described in steps 1 through 4 will be blocked.
```

My understanding is that I need to add interfaces to one or more zones, then add services to the zones that have interfaces.  I also see that I can add source ip addresses to zones.  I also see that I can use rich rules to define the configurations.  But I have never configured a firewall before.  **Can someone show me how to translate the use case above into specific zones/interfaces/services/sources in `firewalld` on a remote `CentOS 7` web server.**

Also, `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` says that the `default zone` is `public`.  What should the `default zone` be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also check out [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD) page on the Fedora Wiki.
I think you will want to use the drop zone because it's the most strict way.

- create an advanced rule so that you can connect from your ip to port 22 (or your different ssh port) with `firewall-cmd ---permanent -zone=home --add-forward-port=port=22:proto=tcp:toaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and allow your own ip address with the next step
- `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" allow'` for all the ip addresses
- add service http, https and so on (this is for all the users now) with `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-service=<service>`
- run `firewall-cmd --reload` to apply these permanent rules
- change your interface to drop with `firewall-cmd --zone=drop --add-interface=<interface>`, you might have to remove it from the previous zone (check it with `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` if firewalld allows an interface to be in multiple zones which I don't know
- if you don't loose your ssh access everything should work and you have to run the last command again but now with the --permanent switch.

But how do you want to allow access from a specific list of users in your web application?
Of course the configuration I explained also only works if every user has a static ip address.

EDIT:
Here is a small explanation on the zones concept. This feature actually isn't so useful for servers but a better example are notebooks. You might want to automatically share your music via dlna when you are at home. In this case you will open the dlna port in the home zone and configure NetworkManager so that it switches your firewall zone to home if you are in your home WiFi or Ethernet LAN. However the default zone should be `public` because if you join a public wifi hotspot you automatically different rules for public networks where this share mustn't be enabled. If you want to reach a home server via ssh from outside your home network for example you wouldn't use firewall rules but other security technologies, the firewall should be configured in 'public' and allow connections from everywhere by default on the ssh port. To secure this highly attackable ssh access then you need to configure it to use client certificate authentication only and a program which is called fail2ban which recognizes and blocks brute force attacks because your ip changes when travelling. Web servers also have specific features to restrict access for example.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to respond to this unanswered question. If I use `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" allow'`, will that block all ip addresses except the one in the rich rule?

Comment: Yes, in drop zone every connection is blocked even if a port is open, that's the reason why you have to open ports as well as making exceptions for the ips. With the rich rule you make these ip exceptions (the firewall will use allow instead of drop policy then for this connection)

Comment: Thank you.  I think I understand, but am hoping you can clarify just a bit more please.  You have a `drop zone` for `http/s` and a `home zone` for `ssh`? What is the role/function of the `interface`(s)?  I think your responses to these two questions would enable me to frame other postings separately.

Comment: Ok sorry for that. I added an explanation for you.